# Include pom property value in bamboo release name

Tags: maven, bamboo

I would like to change the name of my releases in Bamboo, to include the version of the project in the name of the release.
The version is in the parent pom.xml, as such:

```
<properties>
  <myproject.version>1.2.3</myproject.version>
  ...
</properties>
```

So I need to find a way to take the version from the POM then use it as a variable in my release name.

I tried using the extension Maven POM value extractor, however I didn't get to make it work. I used "specify specific element", "result" as variable type, and "myproject.version" in POM element but it couldn't find it. Maybe it is because I didn't speicfy in POM element that myproject.version is in property, but I don't know how to do that. I tried putting properties{myproject.version} but it seems it's not it.

Do you have any idea how I could proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I had to do exactly as I said in the question, however the value is not properties{myproject.version} but properties(myproject.version)